# Find $F ^{−1} (u)$, for $u ∈ (0, 1)$ by solving the equation $u = F(x)$ for $x$

Tags: probability, statistics, graphing-functions, inverse-function

I am working through a problem.  I began with the pdf: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha*e^{-\alpha|x|}$, where $\alpha > 0$ and $x ∈ (−∞,∞)$.  I found the cdf to be: $$F(x) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2}e^{\alpha*x}&\text{if}\, x\leq 0\\
 1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\alpha*x}&\text{if}\, x>0\end{cases}
$$
Now I must:

Find $F ^{−1} (u)$, for $u ∈ (0, 1)$ by solving the equation $u = F(x)$ for $x$.  Possibly helpful: Consider $0 < u ≤\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2} ≤ u < 1$ separately. Plot $F^{-1}(u)$.

My question: Can somebody please translate what this means?  I do not understand what is being asked, maybe if it was stated differently I can get it.  Below is my attempt at moving forward, but I need help.

My attempt:

Find $F^{-1}$ by solving $F(x)$ for $x$:
$$u = \frac{1}{2}e^{\alpha*x} $$
$$ln(2u) = \alpha*x$$
$$x = \frac{ln(2u)}{\alpha}$$
$$and$$
$$u = 1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\alpha*x}$$
$$(2)(1-u)=e^{-\alpha*x}$$
$$ln(2)+ln(1-u)=-\alpha*x$$
$$x = \frac{ln(2)+ln(1-u)}{-\alpha}$$

Comment: So now $x = F^{-1}(u)$ here and you are done

Comment: This is a 
[Lapace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution). In the notation of the link, you have $\mu=0$ and $b = 2/\alpha.$ The quantile function (inverse CDF) is given near the top. If your purpose is to use the quantile function for simulation, note the 3rd bullet under 'Related Distributions', where a Laplace RV is equated to the difference of two exponential RVs and the latter can be easily simulated in terms of a standard uniform RV.